# Blazor server pwa

Tags: c#, blazor, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to find out if it's possible to make a PWA with Blazor server.

It seems to me the way some are "solving" it , is by copy pasting the manifest.json from a webassembly app to a server app.

This made me wondering, why does Microsoft not provide a --pwa flag on the dotnet run blazorserver but only on the web assembly if it's as simple as that.

Thanks!

Comment: Blazor server, by architecture, is controlled from the server-side. Every event in the browser is sent to the server, the server modifies the state and sends the updated DOM difference which gets applied on the client-side. PWAs, by design, are supposed to be used offline. There is a fundamental incompatibility in their objectives and design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially yes: it is possible. But the only benefit you get by doing this is being able to install the application on a device. As Mayur Ekbote stated, blazor server runs on the server and can therefore not access all the other features provided by a PWA. This also explains why Microsoft has not provided a --pwa flag, it's essentially useless. Though I suppose the install feature alone might be worth making it a PWA.

If you want to make your blazor server a PWA, you need to have both a manifest.json and a registered service worker. The browser won't pick it up as a PWA otherwise. For more expansive installation requirements, check [this](https://web.dev/install-criteria/).

As you already described, the easiest way to do this is to copy over the service worker and manifest from a webassembly project and add it to the server project.

Comment: You can still include a service worker in your wwwroot folder and reference it in Layout file.  The browser will pick this up and register it.  Some PWA functionality should be available such as push notifications.

Comment: _"blazor server runs on the server and can therefore not access all the other features provided by a PWA."_ 
Can you explain why? If I do little javascript, I should be able to push notification when app is closed, access file system, sensors etc..